# Hover effect to make background rectangle of nav bar transition up

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar, nav

I have a nav bar where each link is a different colored rectangle. I'd like to have a hover effect where when you hover over the rectangle it moves up and when you're on the page, it stays up. I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do this in CSS though.

This is what I have at the moment:
[Nav Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JfBS.png)

```css
/* Header
    ===============*/

header {
  background: #2EBBDC;
  color: white;
  min-height: 4.375em;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding .logo {
  width: 550px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.about {
  background: #29A448;
  padding: 5px 15px 100px;
}

.resources {
  background: #3171A2;
  padding: 5px 15px 100px;
}

.meet {
  background: #FF9950;
  padding: 5px 15px 100px;
}

.book {
  background: #7F55CF;
  padding: 5px 15px 100px;
}

.shop {
  background: #DD302C;
  padding: 5px 15px 100px;
}

.news {
  background: #F99799;
  padding: 5px 15px 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html" class="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html" class="resources">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="meet.html" class="meet">Meet Us At...</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html" class="book">Book Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" class="shop">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html" class="news">In the News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `overflow: hidden` and `transform: translateY()`.

#### Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  background: #555656;
}

.menu>ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.menu a:hover {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.menu>ul>li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background: #efefef;
}

.menu>ul>li:nth-child(even) a {
  background: #FAFAFB;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="about.html" class="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html" class="resources">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="meet.html" class="meet">Meet Us At...</a></li>
    <li><a href="book.html" class="book">Book Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.html" class="shop">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.html" class="news">In the News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So sorry for the wait.  Thanks so much for the answer, this worked perfectly at getting what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer has helped you, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly you actually want to have it move up and then stay up even after the user moves the mouse away from the element, correct?

I don't think using hover and CSS there is a way to do this. Because you actually want to change the position of the element permanently (or at least until refresh) you can't use hover. The best way to do this would be to use an `onmouseenter` event with javascript.

So your CSS will look like this-

```
 header li { 
 text-decoration: none;
 min-height: 50px;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }
```

Your html element will look like this

```
<li onmouseenter="moveUp(this)"><a href="resources.html" class="resources">Resources</a></li>
```

Then at the bottom of your html just before the closing body tag you'll have.

```
<script>
function moveUp(x) {
    x.style.marginTop = "0px";
 }
</script>
```

This will pass the given element into the `moveUp(x)` function as the x parameter and reduce it's top margin to `0`. that's what the `this` keyword does. You could do this other ways as well. You could use absolute positioning and use negative values for the `top` property etc. But by using `onmouseenter` you will only affect the property when the mouse enters the element, not when it exits. Pretty sure if I read your question correctly that's what you wanted to do. Hope this helps.